#  a measurable cardinal  & a real-valued measurable cardinal in the same model?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

Although I know that "ZFC & there exists a measurable cardinal" and "ZFC & there exists a real-valued measurable cardinal" are equiconsistent with one another, I am not sure whether "ZFC & there exists a measurable cardinal k & there exists a real-valued measurable cardinal b" is equiconsistent with ZFC. (Obviously k is not equal to b.)
I would be grateful for an answer.

Comment: The question you're asking is equivalent to asking whether ZFC is inconsistent.

Comment: A measurable cardinal is also real-valued measurable by definition. The consistency strength of the existence of (real-valued) measurable cardinals is much higher than that ZFC.

Comment: First, a technicality: one doesn't compare a large cardinal axiom with ZFC, one compares "the axiom plus ZFC" to ZFC. So yes, your second sentence is correct, but I am not sure what the second sentence has to do with the question. 

Answer #1 to this question gives the link, but this is not something that is immediately evident from the definitions of these two large cardinals. So your answer seems to be rather dogmatic.   

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me interpret the question as asking for a real-valued measurable cardinal that is not measurable, plus another (two-valued) measurable cardinal, which must be above it. For example, in a more extreme form, your question would ask: can the continuum be real-valued measurable while there is also another measurable cardinal?

The answer is yes.

**Theorem.** If there are two measurable cardinals, then there is a forcing extension in which the smaller one becomes the continuum and real-valued measurable, and the larger one remains measurable.

Proof. If $\kappa\lt\lambda$ are both measurable cardinals in $V$, then the forcing to add $\kappa$ many random reals will make $\kappa$ into the continuum and still real-valued measurable (by a result of Solovay), and the larger measurable cardinal $\lambda$ remains measurable, by the Levy-Solovay theorem, because the forcing was much smaller than $\lambda$. QED

**Corollary.** The following are equiconsistent.

1. There are two measurable cardinals.
2. There are two real-valued measurable cardinals.
3. There is a non-measurable real-valued measurable cardinal and a measurable cardinal.
4. The continuum is real-valued measurable and there is another measurable cardinal.

Proof. Statement 1 implies 4 in a forcing extension, by the argument above. Statement 4 implies statement 3 directly. Statement 3 implies statement 2 directly. Statement 2 implies statement 1 in an inner model. QED

Of course, one can generalize the arguments to handle any number of real-valued measurable cardinals--three instead of two, or any cardinal number---with measurable cardinals above them.